# How do I know if a arrow key was pressed and not released?

Tags: .net, winforms, event-handling

How do I know if a arrow key was pressed and not released? The `OnKeyDown` event is sent continuously...

EDIT: We would like to get only one notification even if the user keep the botton pressed for minutes.

Thanks.

Comment: Windows Forms? WPF? Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

The `OnKeyUp` event fires when the key is released. `OnKeyDown` keeps firing because keys repeat when they are held down.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nullable DateTime, and set the current time on your first key down event, and set it to null on the key up event. If the time span is more than a selected value, say one second, then the user is pressing down the key.

Comment: So it's not down if the key was pressed half a second ago??

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this is a Winforms question, it is not a problem in WPF with the Keyboard class.  Keeping track of the KeyDown and KeyUp events isn't reliable, you can miss a notification when your app gains or loses the focus with the key down.  You need a bit of pinvoke help:

```
    public static class NativeMethods {
        public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key) {
            return GetKeyState(key) < 0;
        }

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetKeyState(Keys key);
    }
```