# Check when arrow keys are pressed?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

How can I check if an arrow key (dunno, the right key for example) is pressed?

Comment: Um, how about [binding a keydown listener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know if a arrow key was pressed and not released?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469939/how-do-i-know-if-a-arrow-key-was-pressed-and-not-released)

Comment: Read this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589130/check-if-delete-key-is-pressed/7527570#7527570

Comment: Which language is this question about? ‍♂️

Comment: @Scott are the tags not loading for you? They clearly say [vb.net] 

Comment: @Saturn, yeah, they are not loading for me

Comment: @Scott ah, I see. Well at least you can tell from the answer that it's clearly VB.NET, but I guess maybe not even answers are loading for you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `KeyPreview` Property to true on Form load

after that you can use the KeyDown / KeyPress event.

```
    Private Sub main_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    '40 = ArrowkeyDown 38= ArrowKeyUp
    If Not e.KeyValue = 40 AndAlso Not e.KeyValue = 38 Then Exit Sub
    'Key Down / Up Code
End Sub
```