# how to press [Enter] catch the Enter but not to Fall line?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-5.0

how to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> - catch the Enter but not to Fall line ?

for example, i have this:

```
 private void txtPlace_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
               // do somthing
            }
        }
```

and i don't want to Fall line

i work on Windows-Mobile - C#

thanks in advance

Comment: When you mean Fall line, you mean move the cusor to the next line?

Answer (score 2):

Checkout my answer from this Post:

[Check when arrow key are pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574235/check-when-arrow-keys-are-pressed/5577728#5577728)

You have to activate your `KeyPreview` event to true to listen to your keypress Event

So for your problem:

```
    Private Sub frm_YourForm(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(Keys.Return) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
   e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}